# SQL query to get the subject with the max score

Tags: sql, arrays, google-bigquery, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

```
name    subject classroom   Total_Score  term   session 
jane     eng     phase1      79          1      2016/2017
jane     math    phase1      56          1      2016/2017
jane     eng     phase1      98          2      2016/2017
jane     math    phase1      87          2      2016/2017
jack     eng     phase1      94          1      2016/2017
jack     math    phase1      45          1      2016/2017
jack     eng     phase1      79          2      2016/2017
jack     math    phase1      89          2      2016/2017
jane     eng     phase2      55          1      2017/2018
jane     math    phase2      37          1      2017/2018
jack     math    phase2      45          1      2017/2018
jack     eng     phase2      59          2      2017/2018
```

Hi, I have this table and I am trying to get the subject a student got the max score in the term and session. The expected result is supposed to look like the table below

```
name   subject   classroom  max_score  term     session
jane     eng     phase1      79          1      2016/2017
jane     eng     phase1      98          2      2016/2017
jack     eng     phase1      94          1      2016/2017
jack     math    phase1      89          2      2016/2017
jane     eng     phase2      55          1      2017/2018
jack     eng     phase2      59          2      2017/2018
```

I tried the following query

```
SELECT
  distinct name, subject, classroom, max(Total_Score), term, session
FROM
  ranktable
 group by name, classroom, term, session, subject
 order by term
```

but it does not return the desired output. I will appreciate any help I can get. I am relatively new to SQL

Comment: Are you using MySQL or SQL Server?

Comment: Pick a Database Server.. any database server

Comment: I removed the conflicting database tags. Please retag only the relevant database.

Comment: Added `google-bigquery` tag back to question. From my long experience here on SO - when user tags the question with mysql, sql server and google-bigquery - it is in most cases (if not all) a big-query related!

Comment: @MJH I am using Mysql and bigquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cross database solution is to filter with a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*
from mytable t
where t.total_score = (
    select max(t1.total_score)
    from mytable t1
    where 
        t1.name = t.name 
        and t1.term = t.term 
        and t1.session = t.session
)
```

This gives you the row with top score per `name`, `term` and `session`.

Comment: Thank you so much for this.

Comment: @wyn: I don’t really have one. The MySQL documentation and Stack Overflow are my main sources.

Comment: Okay. I will come back here for more then :o)

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT AS VALUE ARRAY_AGG(t ORDER BY Total_Score DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] 
FROM `project.dataset.table` t
GROUP BY name, classroom, term, session
```

Comment: Thanks. This also works. Can you share any resource where I can learn more about bigquery?

Comment: consider voting up the answers which you found helpful!  as of resources - start with https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs

Comment: Thanks for sharing

Comment: sure. see you later with BigQuery questions :o)